# Annotations in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony4

I try to develop with Symfony 4 so I follow the tutorial on symfony.com

I've got an error when I try to access at :

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

This is the error :

> [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 7 in method App\Controller\HomeController::home() in /Users/*****/Documents/ProjetSymfo4/my-project/config/routes/../../src/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/Users/*****/Documents/ProjetSymfo4/my-project/config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.

I already ran

> composer require annotations

And it is installed

```
In composer.json : 

"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
```

This is my project :

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the issue and how to fix it

As you can see on my screen I wrote

```
/**
* @Route('/')
*/
```

However to work we have to put " instead of '

```
/**
* @Route("/")
*/
```

Comment: And I suspect you added a use statement as well.

Comment: You should accept this answer if it corrected the problem

Comment: thanks. symfony should not be so quote sensitive.